# PHP shell_exec compound commands to run in the backgrouund

Tags: php, bash

I have several CSV files I'm trying to load into the same data table by running a concurrent load data command via mysql in the terminal. The table starts out empty with no indexes.

When each load data command finishes, I want the command to hit a URL to say that load data has finished, so I can do some cleanup stuff like remove the csv files and email sysadmin etc.

I can get the mysql command to execute (on it's own) and send it's output to null, and this works in PHP for skipping ahead to the next loop.

I can get the curl command to execute after the mysql command using &&

If I try this in a shell on the server via SSH, the ending & makes it run in the background.

However, the exact same command run via shell_exec() or exec() in PHP waits for the whole command to finish.

I understand I can use mysqlimport to import many files into many tables at once, but I can't find a way to use it to import many files into one table.

I want to set mysql off doing N load data commands and continue the PHPP script without waiting for the response.

Command currently using:

```
mysql --host=localhost --user='user' --password='pass' --database='db' --local-infile -e \"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to_1.csv'  INTO TABLE table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (field1, field2, field3)\" >/dev/null 2>&1 && curl 'http://my.url?p=1&j=2&csv=1' >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

And the PHP making that command:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $fileNumber; $i++){
                
    //launch mysql passing proper details
        $command = "mysql --host=localhost --user='".DB_DATA_USER."' --password='".DB_DATA_PASSWORD."' --database='".DB_DATA_NAME."' --local-infile";
                        
    //tell mysql to execute a load data query and send the results to null
        $command .= " -e \"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to_".$i.".csv'  INTO TABLE ".$table." FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '".PHP_EOL."' (field1, field2, field3)\" >/dev/null 2>&1 ";
                    
    //after mysql finishes, curl the update url and send curls output to null, doing the whole lot in the background (so loop continues)
        $command .= " && curl 'http://my.url?p=1&j=2&csv=".$i."' >/dev/null 2>&1 &";
                    
    exec($command);

}
```

**Things I've tried**

Instead of using && between commands, I've tried to pipe | mysql output to curl. This unfortunately results in the curl command being executed before the mysql load data command finishes for some reason.

So to clarify the question, how can I adjust the command OR php code so that it's not waiting for the response when shell_exec or exec is called?

The command works in its current form. What's confusing is that when executing the command via terminal it goes immediately back to input, but via PHP it waits for the result.

Thanks muchly.

**Answer:**

I finally sorted it using a bash script per command pair, and calling that script sending the total output to /dev/null.

Then the only limit was the table lock timeout for my inndb tables. Turns out having them run in parralel is SLOWER than running one load data at a time into the same table - presumably juggling several inserts buffers to the same table takes more time than simply saturating the insert rate from one CSV at a time.

Cheers for the help.

Comment: You would ideally need some kind of background  process manager solution, like Apache airflow, rather than trying to implement this on your own.

Comment: You are running 2 commands and only the 2nd one will run in the BG after the 1st one will succeed.
I think that it will better creating a BASH script to run those 2, taking the variable data from the environment variables - you can use PHP putenv before running the BASH script and then run a single BASH script in the background.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error here. Adding ` > /dev/null 2>&1 &` to the end of every command makes the function `exec` returns immediately.

Comment: @Enrico Dias - if you put a single & at the end of both, for me they run simultaneously - I need the second curl command to fire off only when the first mysql command is finished. - Edit: actually thinking about it if I dynamically create each bash script on the fly then call each in tje background, that should do it?

Comment: @Gal Gur-Arie - if running a bash script, how can I get the $i worth of commands to run at once? But also have every curl command wait for the corresponding mysql command to finish?               The reason for me doing this is to try and get simultaneous mysql load data commands feeding the same table.       - Edit: actually thinking about it if I dynamically create each bash script on the fly then call each in tje background, that should do it?

Comment: As I've wrote before. you can use the PHP function [putenv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) before running the bash script to pass those variables.
for example, in the PHP putenv('CURR_INDEX='.$i); before running the bash script, in the bash get ${CURR_INDEX} variable.

Comment: You can fork parallel processus using proc_open() https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php